# Excel: Combining IF Statement and QUARTILE

Tags: excel

in this case the answers of excel is correct, but in the cell appear #value.

Apparently the error is in the empty cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXv3L.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an array formula. Try entering it using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.